# Store output in variable & use variable in command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I am trying to run a command and store it in a variable.

```
length=`last | grep foouser | wc -l`
```

It works fine but when I add a variable to the command it breaks.

```
value=$1
length=`last | grep $value | wc -l`
```

How can I get this second example to work by acceptomg a variable?

Comment: What, exactly, breaks? Also, you probably want to use `$value` in place of `$1` in the `grep` command.

Comment: Ok yes apologies that was meant to be $value after `grep`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need `wc`:

```
length=$(last | grep -c "$value")
```

You could improve the variable names

```
num_logins=$(last | grep -c "$username")
```

Answer (score 4):

You should quote your variables properly. If they contain spaces your script might break:

```
value="$1"
length="$(last | grep "$value" | wc -l)"
```

Comment: Quoting `$value` as the argument to `grep` is important. Quoting the RHS of the two assignments is less so; word-splitting isn't performed, so I'm not sure there's any problem with leaving them unquoted (although it doesn't hurt to quote them, either).

Comment: still not luck, I am entering `value="foouser" /n length="$(last | grep "$value" | wc -l)"` then trying to echo `$lenght` and it returns nothing @Benoit @chepner

Comment: You typed `lenght` by accident here. Are you mistyping at your terminal as well?

Comment: I think you should use brackets properly  `"${value}"`.